# C# Connect to database in separate thread

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, multithreading

I have an application that sits in the taskbar and periodically checks a database (via SQLConnection).  If the database is unreachable, it just shows a red status on the notify icon, and nothing else.  This is intended since the users will be on laptops traveling between facilities, and the database is only reachable on an internal network or when connected via VPN.

The issue I'm having is that when the database is unreachable, I'd still like the notify icon context menu to be responsive.  Currently if the user tries to interact with the menu while the database is attempting to connect, the thread is locked up with the connection attempt.

What I'd like is for the database connection to happen in a separate thread, but I know that sharing the connection object between threads is a bad thing to try to do.  Once the database has connected, I need to query it from the original thread.  Is there any good way to do this?

I know that I could have a function that rus in a new thread and simply checks if the connection fails or not, then if that returns success the original thread could move on and connect it's own database object.  But that method seems like a bad workaround.  Ideas?

Thanks!

---

Thanks for the suggestions - I have learned quite a bit from them. In the end, I did what I should have done from the start. The main (UI) thread just kicks off a new thread (which includes database object creation and connection) whenever a periodic database update is needed.

So, like HenkHolterman suggested in a comment to my original message, I really did not need to create the database and run operations with it in separate threads.

I will definitely be interested in using SqlConnection.OpenAsync once I've made the upgrade to VS2010.

Thanks again.

Comment: Why do you need to query in the original thread? It could block again.

Answer (score 7):

A `SqlConnection` does not have thread affinity requirements so you can create and open it on a separate thread and pass the reference back to the UI thread. So long as you do not call any properties or methods on the same instance simultaneously from multiple threads you should not have any problems.

Use the `Task` class (System.Threading.Task) to start this operation in the background and then call `ContinueWith` to transfer ownership of the instance back to the UI thread.

```
public class TrayIconForm : Form
{
  private SqlConnection connection = null;

  private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs args)
  {
    TaskScheduler ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
      {
        var sql = new SqlConnection();
        sql.ConnectionString = "your connection string";
        sql.Open();
        return sql;
      }).ContinueWith((task =>
      {
        connection = task.Result;
        // You can access other UI elements here as needed.
      }), ui);
  }
}
```

With the new `async` and `await` keywords to be introduced in C# 5.0 and available now via the Async CTP you can do this.

```
private async void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
  connection = await Task.Run(() =>   // TaskEx.Run in the CTP
    {
      var sql = new SqlConnection();
      sql.ConnectionString = "your connection string";
      sql.Open();
      return sql;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the new [C# Async CTP.](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=9983)  This will allow you to stay on the UI thread, therefore reducing complexity.

[SqlConnection.OpenAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.openasync%28v=VS.110%29.aspx)

Comment: A little adventurous?  And not really an option when the .Open() blocks for many seconds.

Comment: Looks like a good solution, but I haven't decided to go through the arduous company process of ordering an upgrade to VS2010 yet - still on VS2008.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @HenkHolterman I assume you've tried it.  I've had really good experience with this programming model in F#, and feel strongly about recommending it in C# as well.

Comment: @HenkHolterman  Spirit of asynchronous programming is to ask for a long-running action to be performed, and supply a call-back, such as ContinueWith in Brian Gideon's code.  The difference is in keeping everything relating to your app on the same thread, so that there's less risk of breaking things due to threading/synchronization.  This was available even in .NET 1.1, how's this adventurous?  What did i miss?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.openasync%28v=VS.110%29.aspx

Comment: +1: This is definitely how I would do things moving forward. The `await` keyword makes this super easy and elegant in my opinion.

Comment: I just saw your edit...I didn't know there was going to be `SqlConnection.OpenAsync`. Even better!

Comment: OpenAsync() also addresses my concerns. Leaves the Fx4.5 requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) object should solve your problem in a simple way, though more accurately you'd want to use threading to try opening the connection, leaving the UI thread ready to receive user input.

Comment: Once the background thread has opened the connection, how do I interact with it from the UI thread?  Do I need to create the connection object in the UI thread, pass it to the connection thread, and continue once the connection thread finishes?

Comment: That entirely depends on what you need to do with that connection. Be very careful with thread safety. If you use an object that is shared in scope between the two threads, be careful to lock the object while using it.

Comment: You could simply pass the opened connection to the Completed event.