# Stop SqlConnection.Open() from hanging with invalid access

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have a program where the user will be selecting an SQL server (which is populated with all available SQL instances) and then a database within said selected server. The program uses a hard-coded user-id and password which other parts of the program use to access the database. If the user accidentally selects a database which does not have this username/password, it hangs when I select the Server, and gives me the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL
>   Server. The Server was not found or was not accessible.

Is there a way to keep this from hanging and instead just pop up with a message immediately (or to set a max time to wait for SQL Response)?

My code to connect is below:

```
Private Sub cboServers_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboServers.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim dbList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    Dim connectString As String
    Dim selectSQL As String
    Dim server As String

    If cboServers.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("please select a server")
        Return
    End If
    Try
        server = cboServers.Text
        connectString = "Server=" & server & " ;Initial Catalog=master; User Id=*****; password=*******;"

        Dim sqlConn = New SqlConnection(connectString)
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT NAME from sys.databases;", sqlConn)
        Dim sqlDA As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter
        sqlDA.SelectCommand = cmd

        sqlConn.Open()
        'Dim conn As SqlConnection
        'conn = New SqlConnection(connectString)
        'conn.Open()

        'selectSQL = "SELECT NAME from sys.databases;"

        'Dim com As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(selectSQL, sqlConn)

        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While (dr.Read)
            dbList.Add(dr(0).ToString)
        End While

        cboDatabases.DataSource = dbList
        sqlConn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        'MessageBox.Show("Server not accessible")
    End Try


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

SqlConnection class has a [ConnectionTimeout property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1), which is 15 seconds by default.
You can set it to lower value to reduce the wait time.

Another way to optimize this would be to offload connection checking to another thread,
there are a few nice C# examples in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213631/c-sharp-connect-to-database-in-separate-thread).